# Mongodb: updating fields in embedded document

Tags: python, mongodb

If I have a document that looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "name": "Homer J. Simpson", 
    "income" : 45000,
    "address": { 
        "street": "742 Evergreen Terrace", 
        "city": "Springfield", 
        "state": "???", 
        "email": "homer@springfield.com", 
        "zipcode": "12345", 
        "country": "USA"
     }
}
```

And want to do an update on some of the fields in the address document (leaving the other ones unchanged), and insert new fields if they do not already exist, such as this:

```
{ 
    "address": {
        "email": "homer@gmail.com", 
        "zipcode": "77788", 
        "latitude" : 23.43545, 
        "longitude" : 123.45553
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do an atomic update all at once, or do you need to loop over the key/values in the new data and do a `.update()` for each one?

Comment: Seems that a simple `$set` will suffice

Comment: A $set on the address in the existing document with the new data will replace the existing data with the new, not update/insert new fields.

Comment: If you don't need to update address, don't list it in a `$set`.

Answer (score 1):

Use dot notation with a `$set` to target multiple embedded fields in a single `update`:

```
{ "$set": {
    "address.email": "homer@gmail.com", 
    "address.zipcode": "77788", 
    "address.latitude" : 23.43545, 
    "address.longitude" : 123.45553
} }
```

Comment: That would work, but I don't know which fields are going to be updated a priori...

Comment: @reptilicus You would still use the same approach, but build up the `$set` keys programmatically.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was talking about.

Comment: Ahh, ok, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

As Sergio metioned use a $set.

```
{address.latitude : "77788"}
```

Comment: But I would still have to use a loop over each of the keys in the new data correct?

Comment: Sorry I was thinking address is an array.